# Slow down (apparently) in process scheduling stepping from Ubuntu 16 to 20

Tags: kernel, 20.04

I have been using Ubuntu to record data from an SDR and processing the collected data for radio astronomical observation.
The max sample rate i could collect was 56 M samples/sec (limit of the sdr) but no problem on the Ubuntu side using home made software (Ubuntu 16). To stay behind other updates i moved to Ubuntu 18 a couple of years ago , the situation was still acceptable but few failures from time to time with overflow indication.
Data are received via a USB 3.0 and overflow indicates software not fast enough.
The above was true until the latest update to Ubuntu 18 where (if i am not wrong) the Kernel was aligned with the same version as Ubuntu 20, after that i had to drop the input rate to about the middle compare with before and still not sure for how long.
I tried to move to a real Ubuntu 20 but the situation was the same, lost of data starting immediately or sometimes after minutes. Last effort was to install the low latency kernel but difficult to notice a difference or decide which one is worst.
Of course, the  software was exactly the same with high priority to critical threads.
The environment is a tower PC with 16 GB memory and an I7 4770 CPU.
Finally (hoping for a miracle)  i moved the whole environment to a laptop with also 16 memory running at 2.6GHz and a 10th generation cpu (I 10875h) with a much better performance than Tower PC in terms of benchmarks but worst for my needs.
Any kind of advice would really be appreciated.

EDIT Add on to the problem:
The application is made in a QT environment where the gui is used only to insert few parameters and the goal is to make data recording aimed to astronomical observations (pulsar detection) with each recording variable from 1 to 4-5 hours.
Very important is the bandwidth of the data to be as large as possible.
as receiver i am using an Ettus sdr receiver with a max of 56Mhz bandwidth at a frequency around 1300Mhz.
The real time process consist of :

Receive block of data from the sdr (float I/Q samples)

Apply an RFI mitigation process (time domain)

Make an FFT  pass to frequency domain

Apply an RFI mitigation in frequency domain

Decimate the data

Write data to disk for a post processing

The software is made of the following layers:

Lib USB

Ettus research interface to interface hardware

User real time thread as interface between Ettus and the rest of application

Threads for the rest of functions

A big buffer pool to pass data and absorb latencies between different layers

EDIT As news I have applied the modifications suggested by Doug , first impression is an evident improvement in the tower PC (to be confirmed) all most no change on the laptop where seems to me that the system is not able to take advantage of the potential cpu power. On the tower i was able to make 1 hour time recording with no problems (then stopped for lack of time),monitoring (htop) the activity cpu use was 200% (whatever it means) and cpu fans at max speed. On the lap top the cpu get engaged for the few seconds of live lower than 100% and fans very quiet.
I would like very much to move the whole environment to the laptop because the tower is producing a lot of radio frequency interference while the laptop is much more silent.

Updates with testing result:

First of all i have to contractic myself , what i said yesterday was the result of a lucky event, the reality is that nothing changed. It appears like there is some sort of casual synchrony, resonance ... call it as you like where thinks look better but as a casualty. The laptop seems to be the worst in any circumstance and actually i had to reduce the transfer rate to be able to see a normal behavior.
In order to reduce the variables, the following test have been done with a single thread application running at high priority on a terminal (no gui) consisting only in a loop receiving buffers from the lower layers.
The loop is interrupted at the first error.
I want to say that i am not alone in suffering for the problem, a friend of mine using my software with only a tower PC but newer and more powerful than mine observed the same deterioration of performances.
The following are the results, for what i can see it looks like latencies in serving interrupts, very strange the different behavior of the 2 machines. Much more cpu load in the tower and much lower cpu frequency while the laptop shows a very small cpu load but high clock rate ???.

Tower and Laptop, same for all cpus:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
```

Turbostat results included as pictures to save the formatting:

[Laptop turbostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQTlc.jpg)

[Tower turbostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50fFu.jpg)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following are the results of  forcing cpu affinity where we have put not a single thread (mine) but also the one added by the underlying  layer (not under my control)  , not sure if the test says something useful.
a pity that we can apply taskset only at process level, could also organize my application in several processes but there is a big contra indication. While now the infra thread communication is solved by passing a buffer address splitting the path in process force to make a physical copy (several times) the whole flux of data.
i do not believe it could be a solution.
In any case, let's forget about the Laptop, which is a new entry but the Tower was running as a charm at 56Mhz and unable to image where could be the problem.
Laptop truncated turbostat trace 12sec period , at 50 Msamples/sec overflow after 1436263 blocks

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt  
0.64    950     2296    36  1.23    0.00  
0.60    2109    16518   47  2.11    0.01  
1.68    1973    38821   38  2.65    0.00    
0.80    3059    47123   36  2.79    0.00  
1.32    3511    87392   37  4.35    0.01  
1.61    3643    112790  52  5.27    0.01  
1.17    4049    98914   38  4.73    0.00  
0.45    1644    10524   37  1.47    0.01  
1.49    4118    116907  38  5.56    0.00  
0.14    1210    2034    38  1.18    0.00  
0.18    1253    3324    38  1.19    0.00  
0.13    948     2039    37  1.16    0.00  
4.47    2304    41744   39  5.44    0.12  
3.94    2501    34164   39  5.42    0.09  
1.41    1046    12146   39  1.45    0.02  
7.49    4243    35073   43  21.15   0.12  
0.59    1499    11795   40  1.50    0.01  
3.16    4407    307462  52  12.31   0.00  
3.08    4448    322628  52  12.70   0.00  
3.08    4452    322723  53  12.74   0.00  
3.09    4448    322486  55  12.79   0.00  
3.10    4445    323027  54  12.84   0.00  
3.11    4433    323140  55  12.86   0.00  
3.09    4449    322441  55  12.90   0.00
```

Tower unable to start at 56MSamples/sec (same as laptop) but apparently more stable at 50 i truncated the trace

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt  
2.70    1697    13945   47  5.96    0.14  
1.30    905    10912    47  4.97    0.01  
1.16    1955    17087   47  5.37    0.00  
1.51    1811    16188   47  5.45    0.01  
0.66    1747    7617    49  5.04    0.01  
0.51    1499    5610    47  4.93    0.01  
0.64    1776    9768    47  5.05    0.01  
0.75    1787    10124   46  5.11    0.01  
0.51    1374    4429    46  4.91    0.01  
6.84    2817    35616   56  10.97   0.09  
1.28    2292    5767    47  5.67    0.04  
9.17    3676    17492   58  16.31   0.03  
8.94    3844    13878   49  17.17   0.01  
1.01    2418    5657    48  5.42    0.03  
4.00    2635    112623  50  7.58    0.01  
9.67    2478    324416  50  10.99   0.00  
9.61    2405    324033  49  10.62   0.00  
9.61    2402    323596  49  10.61   0.00  
9.61    2401    323673  50  10.61   0.00  
9.61    2427    324656  52  10.79   0.00  
9.62    2402    323771  52  10.62   0.00  
9.60    2406    323753  51  10.62   0.00  
9.59    2409    324019  51  10.63   0.00  
9.60    2406    324158  51  10.63   0.00  
9.67    2414    325071  52  10.75   0.00  
9.60    2404    323809  51  10.62   0.00  
9.60    2406    324026  52  10.62   0.00  
9.59    2411    324270  51  10.63   0.00  
9.61    2412    324178  50  10.64   0.00  
9.47    2470    324716  51  11.08   0.00  
9.60    2407    324097  52  10.63   0.00  
9.59    2410    324167  51  10.63   0.00  
9.59    2406    323637  52  10.62   0.00  
10.34   2431    329152  53  11.19   0.13  
10.17   2419    329791  51  11.00   0.03
```

nando

Comment: Your issue is very interesting. I can try to help, but suspect it might take some back and forth, which askubuntu does not like. We, and others that chime in, might have to move to a chat room, eventually. There are a great many possibilities. My first thought is all the retpoline mitigations, which have had a dramatic effect on some, not all, high rate pipes. And it has been getting worse. I'll try compiling a kernel with `CONFIG_RETPOLINE` disabled and compare for a particular pipe test I use. Did you really mean 56,000,000 samples per second, or 18 nanoseconds per sample? Whew, fast!

Comment: Is your application single threaded or multi-threaded? If single threaded, just force CPU affinity, and it'll likely run faster, as the scheduler is not very good at serialized single threaded work flow.

Comment: I suspect you meant 56,000 samples per second, 18 uSec per sample, which seems more reasonable.

Comment: I am only observing about a 7% difference in pipe-test loop times, whereas I has expected more of a difference (based on experience with my older i7-2600K. This was a i5-9600K). Turns out the kernel does not need to be recompiled, just add this to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, `spectre_v2=off spec_store_bypass_disable=on`. I did both ways,

Comment: back on my i7-2600K: Kernel 5.8-rc5: 6.3 uSec / loop. Kernel 4.5: 4.0 uSec / loop. hmmm....

Comment: Doug, Thanks for the attention i have some difficulties in understanding your terms but i try to clarify better my situation. The transfer rate is really 56 mega samples per seconds with I/Q float format so 8 bytes each. Th application is a multi threaded (6 threads) with a long data processing before writing the decimated data to disk. My impression is a drastic change to priority handling because i had the same result with Ubuntu 16 if not setting high priority. Now with or without high priority the result is more or less the same. Please clarify where to make the change, Nando.

Comment: Doug , if ,as you are saying, this is not an interesting topic i have no problems to give you my email: i1ndp.nando@gmail.com which would be much better for me too.

Comment: I found where make the change but had a conflict to find the underscore on my Italian keyboard with US mapping and a short time available and will try again later. What i meant above was "not interesting for askubuntu".

Comment: Sorry, I think we have a language issue. This is very interesting. However, askubuntu is a question and answer forum. Your issue is going to continue to require some back and forth between you and interested readers just to clearly define the issue, yet alone provide an answer. askubuntu does not like a lot of comments is all that I meant. When askubuntu wants us to move to chat, we will. It would be better than e-mail, because then others can also help.

Comment: Please edit your question adding more detail about your workflow. So far I have just been guessing that my pipe-test might be similar. However, I do notice a significant change in the system overhead for the pipe-test, which is not all accounted for with the various vulnerabilities mitigations added over the last few years. Are you also running a GUI? A server, with no GUI and no extra services running might be a better option.

Comment: Interesting results for your tower PC, although I expected higher load average. I wonder if your LapTop is throttling? What CPU frequency scaling driver and governor are you using on both computers? Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. Suggest you run tubostat (linux-tools-common package, I think) to monitor things. Do `sudo ~/turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 12`.

Comment: The next step is to set your CPU frequency scaling governor to 'performance` and to tweek another parameter (it is a different parameter between your LapTop and Tower, because one has HWP (HardWare P-state) control and one doesn't). Further, the easy way to tweek with HWP will not even be available until kernel 5.9. Tower only for now: do: `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and then check it as per above. We also want to set EPB to 0, but I'll have to come back later with how, as I will need to boot a kernel close to what you might be using.

Comment: EPB: Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/power/energy_perf_bias` it should be 6 by default. Do: `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/power/energy_perf_bias` and then check it with the first command. Report back, including turbostat listings as code insertions, not pictures. If you can not format correctly, I'll fix it.

Comment: For your single threaded test did you force CPU affinity? i.e. did you force it to always run on, say, CPU 5? Do `taskset -c 5 program-to-run`. why? to not have CPU switching frequency ramp up latency and exit from deep deep idle latency.

Comment: about 13 turbostat samples into your LapTop capture, it seemed to have a lot more work to do. Any explanation?

Comment: For your LapTop, EPP (as opposed to EPB) should adjust automatically to desired setting. So try performance governor on it also. We might also try disabling HWP at some point, but one step at a time.